# Retirar opções do Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

Estou usando o [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/earthquakes) e gostaria de tirar todas as outras opções (restaurantes, igrejas, escolas, postos, etc,) e deixar apenas o os meus marcadores

Atualmente inicio o mapa assim:

```
function initMap( lat, lng, nome, lojas  ) {
        var myLatLng = {lat, lng};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: nome
        });
     }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta adicionar isso:

```
var styles = {
    default: null,
    hide: [
      {
        featureType: 'poi.business',
        stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'transit',
        elementType: 'labels.icon',
        stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
      }
    ]
  }; //Aqui você define o estilo na qual os ícones ficam invisíveis

map.setOptions({styles: styles['default']}); //Aqui você aplica o estilo ao seu mapa
```

Retirado da própria documentação do Google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/hiding-features

**No seu código** ficaria assim:

```
var styles = {
        default: null,
        hide: [
            {
            featureType: 'poi.business',
            stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        },
        {
        featureType: 'transit',
        elementType: 'labels.icon',
        stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
      }
    ]
  }; 

function initMap( lat, lng, nome, lojas  ) {
    var myLatLng = {lat, lng};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myLatLng
    });

  map.setOptions({styles: styles['hide']});

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: nome
    });
 }
```

Acesse todas os `featureType` no link a seguir: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference#style-features

Comment: No caso eu troquei 'default' para 'hide' `map.setOptions({styles: styles['hide']});`

Comment: Você onde eu encontro essa lista? Tipo a `featureType: 'poi.business',` ?

Comment: @adventistaam olha no fim da pergunta, editei ;)

Comment: Excelente! Muito obrigado!